# Fetching Limited Words In PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, parsing

Have a look at this code
`echo file_get_html('http://www.google.com)->plaintext;`
it will fetch full content from a website. So, my question is how to fetch limited words. Suppose it will fetch only 180 words.. any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fetching from PHP Simple DOM Parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429042/fetching-from-php-simple-dom-parser)

Comment: @andrewsi not duplicate but specified ...

Answer (score 0):

file_get_html creates a DOM object, which requires a full page load/parse so you can't necessarily grab by character count. You can, however, initiate a file handler and fread to a certain amount of bytes:

```
$fh = fopen('google.com');
$data = fread($fh,$length);
fclose($fh);
```

Or this:

```
 $data = substr(file_get_contents('google.com'),$start,$end);
```